# How to link to a multi upload's first child image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

I created an online magazine reader where every page is an image, that are loaded through a multi upload. For some UX reasons, I added a function that would increment each time a new page is uploaded, then I set up a system where the page number is shown in the URL instead of the ID, which gives the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/magazines/magazine-4/pages/1
```

Where 1 is this incremented number instead of the ID.

I would like to know how should I proceed to always get this page number one

Here is some of my files to get you an idea of how I proceeded:

**magazine_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @magazine = Magazine.new(magazine_params)

    if @magazine.save
      (params[:images] || []).each_with_index do |image, index|
        //Increments and saves the current page number
        @magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: index + 1) 
      end
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine créé'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**pages_controller.rb (where I set the page number as an id)**

```
  private

  def set_page
    @magazine = Magazine.find_by(slug: params[:magazine_id])
    @page = @magazine.pages.find_by(page_number: params[:id])
  end

  def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:titre, :apercu, :page_number)
  end
```

**views/_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="images[]">Multi Upload</label>
    <%= file_field_tag 'images[]', type: :file, multiple: true %>
  </div>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
  resources :magazines do
    resources :pages
  end
```

I don't really know what else should I show you. I tried to create something like this

```
def first_page
    self.class.where('page_number = 1', page_number)
  end
```

But it doesn't work at all and seem to try to load the whole class instead of a link.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `pages` association in the magazine instance instead:

```
def first_page
  self.pages.find_by(page_number: 1)
end
```

This of course means that you need to ensure that the page number is unique per magazine:

```
class Page
  validates_uniqueness_of :page_number, scope: :magazine_id
end
```

And you should also [make sure there is a db index](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations):

```
add_index :pages, [:page_number, :magazine_id], unique: true
```

Comment: Don't worry, the uniqueness validation is already made, I didn't find useful to put it here since it wasn't my main concern. It worked like a charm, I'm kinda glad I was close to what I was looking for

Comment: You don't need to do the hack with iterating through the params either - use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and [accepts_nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: The DB index is actually very relevant since the above won't work or will have strange results if there are duplicates.

Comment: I created an index just in case, and while thinking over it, I think there is a way a duplicate could be created (when updating the existing magazine) So thank you !